# Is there a way to multiply objects (non-numbers) by a matrix to create a permutation of the objects?

Tags: matrices, permutations

Consider the matrix 'multiplication' here: [vector $ matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP7GL.png) 
If I were to multiply as usual I would get:$$(c\hspace{3mm}0\hspace{3mm} a+b)$$

However, I wish to ignore any zeros and + symbols so as to produce the answer (c a b), as shown in the image. In other words, I wish to use a matrix to permute objects. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Move the $1$ in the top row to the center, and put a $0$ in the top right corner.

For more on such matrices, see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

Comment: Yes, I understand your solution, but let's assume I cannot do that (too much to explain here). Is there another acceptable way?

Comment: There may be, but without knowing why the way I've given is unacceptable, I cannot say what it could be.

Comment: Well. I will be working with much larger matrices that are part of encryption and I have no control over what they will be. It is too difficult to explain here, but I need to apply the permutation without changing the matrix into a permutation matrix (as, I think, you suggested).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure, then. This seems like more of a computer science problem than a mathematical one, *per se*. Sorry!

Comment: A strange question, I know. But thank you!